# Downmix Quad to Stereo by discarding rear channels

Tags: pro-tools

Protools 11HD - need to downmix / downconvert a Quad track (L/R/Ls/Rs) to Stereo L/R by discarding or nulling Ls/Rs.

There doesn't seem to be an intuitive way of doing this. No downmixer exists in stock PT for Quad to Stereo downmixing.

Comment: I must be missing something obvious here... can you not simply mute the unwanted channels & export the rest to stereo?

Comment: Nope. It's a protools thing

Comment: There seems to be a lot of simple stuff it can't do... jus' saying' ;)

Comment: I'm confused also, and I'm a long-time Pro Tools user. Did you import the audio as a single multichannel track? If so, that's your mistake. Import the audio as four separate tracks. Then you can mix the tracks however you need to.

Comment: @ToddWilcox This is actually part of a wider initiative to work around a limitation in protools. I am mastering a classical album that has a number of different sections that require de-noising with different profiles. I am attempting to use panning to overcome a limitation in the automation where the "volume" automation fades do not accurately represent the actual dB reduction in the fade.  Half-way down the fade should be a 6dB reduction (or 3dB depending...) unfortunately it's not, it's about 19dB. This causes a massive dip at the centre of the crossfade.

Comment: @Tetsujin Just want to again thank-you for your assistance with this question. Sorry, my previous vote of thanks to you was deleted.

Comment: I think the automation shapes are meant to represent **fader** positions, not dB reduction. A fader halfway down on an analog console is more than 6 dB of reduction. It’s a feature for people who are used to mixing analog, not a bug.

Comment: Never said it was a bug - it is a limitation. Try implementing a crossfade between tracks using volume automation. You will immediately see what I mean.